# NoClassDefFoundError in the Spring Mvc form handler

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

I work with a small Spring Mvc project and I get an error in to the time of handling a `POST` request. The error message is provided below,

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/jsps/users/userform.jsp] at line [26]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/jsps/users/userform.jsp] at line [26]

23: 
24:     <spring:url value="/users" var="userActionUrl"/>
25: 
26:     <form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="${userActionUrl}">
27: 
28:         <form:hidden path="id"/>
29: 


Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsps.users.userform_jsp._jspService(userform_jsp.java:1278)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The landing page is here (`list.jsp`) and mapped to the `http://localhost:8080/users`,

[image]

The corresponding controller code,

```
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHome() {

        logger.debug("showHome()");

        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAllUsers(Model model) {

        logger.debug("showAllUsers()");
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAllUsers());
        return "users/list";
    }
```

When I press the `Add User` button, it directs to the address `http://localhost:8080/users/add`. The page shows the file `userform.jsp` and it get the error from there. The respective controller code is provided below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "users/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddUserForm(Model model) {

    logger.debug("showAddUserForm()");

    User user = new User();

    user.setName("mkyong123");
    user.setEmail("test@gmail.com");
    user.setAddress("abc 88");

    //user.setPassword("123");
    //user.setConfirmPassword("123");
    user.setNewsletter(true);
    user.setSex("M");
    user.setFramework(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Spring MVC", "GWT")));
    user.setSkill(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Spring", "Grails", "Groovy")));
    user.setCountry("SG");
    user.setNumber(2);

    model.addAttribute("userForm", user);

    populateDefaultModel(model);
    return "users/userform";
}
```

The necessary code in the `userform.jsp` page is provided below,

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="${userActionUrl}">

    <form:hidden path="id"/>

    <spring:bind path="name">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <form:input path="name" type="text" class="form-control " id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
                <form:errors path="name" class="control-label"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>

 </form:form>
```

I get the error message in the line,

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="${userActionUrl}">
```

This is the controller method suppose to handle the `POST` request,

```
// save or update user
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveOrUpdateUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") @Validated User user,
            BindingResult result, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        logger.debug("saveOrUpdateUser() : {}", user);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            populateDefaultModel(model);
            return "users/userform";
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");

            if(user.isNew()){
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "User added successfully!");
            }else{
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "User updated successfully!");
            }

            userService.saveOrUpdate(user);

            // POST/REDIRECT/GET
            return "redirect:/users/" + user.getId();

            // POST/FORWARD/GET
            // return "user/list";
        }
    }
```

What do I need to change to run it properly?

Comment: class ExpressionEvaluationUtils is old class , looks like you have  dependency on old verion for spring in maven ,

Comment: throw your pom.xml so we can see your spring version

Comment: @sbjavateam The issue was indeed due to the older version of the dependencies in the `pom.xml` file. I updated to all of them to the `RELEASE` and the problem is solve. Can you write it to an answer which can help other users?

Comment: done. hope  it explains main point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

class ExpressionEvaluationUtils it's old class , before spring 4 this class was removed. If you see something like :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils

it means that you have some old version for spring in pom.xml (this class is not anymore in classpath /dependencies in the latest spring version). To solve this , just update dependencies to relevant versrion that you use.